# MessagePack: disable integer compression

Tags: c#, .net, msgpack, messagepack

I am using the `MessagePack for CLI` (https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli) library and I am wondering, if it's possible to disable the integer compression.

For example:

```
// The following collection
object[] { (Int32)10, (Int32)100, (Int32)1000 };
// will look like this after unpacking
MessagePackObject[] { (Byte)10, (Byte)100, (Int16)1000 }
```

This forces me to explicitly convert each item of the collection in order to cast it back to `int[]`, which is quite time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Use directly fixed-sized types:

```
msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> pk(&buffer); 

msgpack::type::fix_uint32 code(0x00);
msgpack::type::fix_uint32 type(123);

pk.pack(code);
pk.pack(type);
```

Comment: Actually my question was directed specifically on the C# implementation of messagepack (https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli). I still cannot find any way to force the serializer to not compress the integers.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe something like this would be useful? `packer.Pack<System.Int32>`. It is from `msgpack-cli/blob/master/test/MsgPack.UnitTest/PackerTest.PackT.cs`. I'm pretty sure that somewhere there is a suitable example in the `test` folder :)